# How to display multiplication symbol (dot) on the axis label in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to display "A·B" on x-axis label (showing it with dot, meaning that A * B), but failed to search.

Can anyone give advice with it?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3])
plt.xlabel(r'$A \cdot  B$')
```

Comment: For further reading: As is explained in detail [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html), within $$ you can use TeX commands to generate almost arbitrarily complex mathematical expressions.